# How to import an SQL Server 2008 table from one DB in to multiple tables in a different DB?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to migrate a table from an old database (SQL Server 2008) in to a new database - also SQL Server 2008 - with a different table structure. It's an old CMS which I am trying to import the user data in to the new, different, CMS.

The original table has 5 columns, username, password, email, firstname, surname.

In the new database this information is stored seperately over 3 other tables.

**tbl_Contacts**

Contact_ID, Phone, Email

**tbl_user_contact**
Contact_ID, User_ID

**tbl_user**
User_ID, UserName, Password, firstname, surname

Most of the data goes in to `tbl_user` and I think I will need to put the information in to here first to create a unique `User_ID`.
Then I will need to add the phone and email data to tbl_contacts to create a Unique `Contact_ID` and then finally create a new entry in `tbl_user_contact` and import the `Contact_ID` and `User_ID`.

I'm sure this must be possible but I have no idea where to start. I have about 900 users to import in to the new CMS, can this be done with just SQL? Maybe a stored procedure or would it be best to create a .net script?

This will be a one time import because once it's done, the admin will add users with the `'add user'` functionality already built in to the CMS.

Any questions, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways how to achieve the desired solution. I provide you the one-of-the-many possible option how it may be implemented.

```
create table original_table
(
    username nvarchar(100), 
    [password] nvarchar(100), 
    email nvarchar(100), 
    firstname  nvarchar(100), 
    surname  nvarchar(100)
);

insert into original_table (username, [password], email, firstname, surname) values
('user1', 'jhwe7y784', 'john@mail.com', 'John', 'Smith'),
('user2', 'srce45', 'bob@mail.com', 'Bob', 'Rolan'),
('user3', '4c5456656c', 'katty@mail.com', 'Katty', 'Moon'),
('user4', 'hhhh8737y4434', 'katty@mail.com', 'Katty', 'Moon');


-- prepare (adding unique id to original table)
select row_number() over(order by email) [id]
, username, [password], email, firstname, surname
into #original_table_with_id
from original_table;


-- tbl_Contacts 
create table tbl_Contacts (Contact_ID int, Phone nvarchar(20), Email nvarchar(50));

insert into tbl_Contacts (Contact_ID, Phone, Email)
select distinct Contact_ID, Phone, Email
from (
    select id /*unique contact identifier*/ [Contact_ID]
    , '' [Phone]
    , email [Email]
    from #original_table_with_id
) as t


-- tbl_user 
create table tbl_user ([User_ID] int, UserName nvarchar(100), [Password] nvarchar(100), firstname nvarchar(100), surname nvarchar(100));

insert into tbl_user (User_ID, UserName, Password, firstname, surname)
select distinct [User_ID], UserName, [Password], firstname, surname
from (
    select rank() over(order by username /*unique user identifier*/) [User_ID]
    , username
    , Password
    , firstname
    , surname
    from #original_table_with_id
) as t;


-- tbl_user_contact 
create table tbl_user_contact (Contact_ID int, [User_ID] int);

insert into tbl_user_contact (Contact_ID, User_ID)
select distinct c.Contact_ID, u.[User_ID]
from #original_table_with_id o
join tbl_Contacts c on c.Contact_ID = o.id /*unique contact identifier*/
join tbl_user u on u.username = o.username /*unique user identifier*/


-- results
select username, [password], email, firstname, surname from #original_table_with_id;
select u.UserName, u.[Password], c.Email, u.firstname, u.surname
from tbl_user_contact uc
join tbl_Contacts c on c.Contact_ID = uc.Contact_ID
join tbl_user u on u.[User_ID] = uc.[User_ID]
```

Result

**original table**

```
username    password        email           firstname   surname
---------------------------------------------------------------
user1       jhwe7y784       john@mail.com   John        Smith
user2       srce45          bob@mail.com    Bob         Rolan
user3       4c5456656c      katty@mail.com  Katty       Moon
user4       hhhh8737y4434   katty@mail.com  Katty       Moon
```

**three tables joined together**

```
UserName    Password        Email           firstname   surname
---------------------------------------------------------------
user1       jhwe7y784       john@mail.com   John        Smith
user2       srce45          bob@mail.com    Bob         Rolan
user3       4c5456656c      katty@mail.com  Katty       Moon
user4       hhhh8737y4434   katty@mail.com  Katty       Moon
```

Conclusion

on my opinion the Firstname and the Lastname fields must be a part of the tbl_Contacts table, but anyway it is just the simplified version of possible solution

---

### Mics

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help with that. Will give it a go today and see how I get on.

Comment: Found a problem @andrey. Not all the entries have an email address and I can't find a unique identifier between the two tables I'm trying to merge.
All the final table (**tbl_user_contact**) requires is the 'contact_id' and 'user_id', I've got all the other information working thanks to your help. 
One option I thought about is when inserting the data I could maybe create a new unique identifier column which increments on each insert, do this for both tables and then that will give me a unique id to then insert in to 'tbl_user_contact' would this work?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @Andrey. 
Still having an issue with the contact identifier. `Contact_ID` doesn't match up with `o.id` because `Contact_ID` is an incremental column but the `o.id` is more random. An example is `Contact_ID` = 1835 but `o.id` = 1008.

Comment: Just had a thought - the import for `Contact_ID` on `tbl_Contacts` starts from 1835 and increments by 1 every row, so that is a constant. Is there a way to say, start from 1835 and pair it up with the first `o.username` from `User_ID` 755 which will also increment by one.

Comment: if you doing everything correctly, there can not be any difference between  `o.id` and `c.Contact_ID` because they are THE SAME (see update in the post)

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help! After some tweaks and re-reading your example above, I now have everything I require. The big bit I missed was creating the new table with the ids!